How to get synchronous load using async and await in jquery on loadedmetadata?
I want to use jquery to get audio duration in synchronous by await.
I want to get the alert messages in this order :
   111 
   222 leng=1.549188
   333 duration=1.549188 
   444 

But I get the asynchronous order :
   111 
   333 duration=9999 
   444 
   222 leng=1.549188 

How to fix it ?
var duration = 99999 ; 

async function getAudioUrlDuration(src, callBackFun) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = src;
    await $(audio).on("loadedmetadata", function(){
        callBackFun( audio.duration );
        duration = audio.duration ;
    });
}
function callBackFun3(leng){ 
    alert('222 leng='+leng) ; 
}
var src = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" ;

async function aaa(){
  alert(111);
  await getAudioUrlDuration(src, callBackFun3 )  ; 
  alert( '333  duration='+duration ) ; 
  alert(444);
} 
 
 aaa();


by definition async/await is asynchronous ... so How to get synchronous load using async and await is an oxymoron - it looks like you want to await a jquery .on call - but that doesn't return a Promise, so, you can't do that - maybe like this https://pastebin.com/iA1pLVeY

Does this answer your question? How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?

The issue is the on function of jQuery doesn't return a promise to await for, you need to turn the getAudioUrlDuration function to return a promise which will be resolved on the on callback success.
var duration = 99999; 
async function getAudioUrlDuration(src) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = src;
    // Return a promise that resolves when the loadedmetadata event is triggered
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        $(audio).on("loadedmetadata", function(){
            duration = audio.duration;
            resolve(audio.duration);
        });
            
        $(audio).on("error", function() {
            reject(new Error("Failed to load audio metadata")); // Reject the promise with an error
        });
    });
}

function callBackFun3(leng){ 
    alert('222 leng=' + leng); 
}

var src = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3";

async function aaa(){
    try {
      alert(111);
      var audioDuration = await getAudioUrlDuration(src);
      callBackFun3(audioDuration);  
      alert('333 duration=' + duration); 
      alert(444);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    
}

aaa();


Thanks for the answer. It works. But how to handle error in the Promise ?  I want to return 0  if the url is invalid or unreachable.

@user2818066, I just updated the answer with the code to handle errors, first you need to reject the promise inside the on('error') callback, and surround your code in the aaa function with try/catch
